# SQL Query Clarification Required

Tags: sql

I have a table consisting of the following columns:

```
billid, patientid, doctorid, fees
```

How do i display the doctors who treat more than one patient?

TRIED THE FOLLOWING CODE and got it.

```
select doctorid from tableName GROUP BY doctorId HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT patientid) > 1
```

Thanks :)

Comment: More info please and what have you tried?

Comment: have you actually tried to come up with a solution? I'll give you a hint: use group by and having

Comment: I am a beginner. Got confounded by the quest. Thanks. :)

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677679/sql-query-clarification). The other one is much more clear :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT doctorID
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY doctorID
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT patientid) > 1
```

These are basic SQL queries. If you have trouble with something like this, you should really get to some SQL tutorial or book first.

Comment: A beginner now.Yeah Will do that first. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select doctorid, count(patientid) from table1 group by doctorid having COUNT (DISTINCT patientid) > 1 ;
```

This will show you the doctor list having more than 1 distinct patient

Comment: Thanks krishna sahoo :)

Answer (score 0):

on the given information if you will just select doctorid  who is treating more than one patient with this query

```
select doctorid from tableName GROUP BY doctorId HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT patientid) > 1
```

and then you can use that doctorid in rest of your operations