# SQL Query Clarification

Tags: sql

I have two tables doctor and billing. I wish to view the dname,doctorid and sum(fees) of doctors treating more than one patient.

doctor table columns are as follows:

```
doctorid,dname
```

billing table columns are as follows:

```
billid,patientid,doctorid,fees
```

I tried the following code. But got an error stating SQL cmd not properly ended:

```
SELECT d.dname,b.doctorid,Sum(b.fees)as "TotalFees" FROM billing b,doctor d ON b.doctorid=d.doctorid
GROUP BY b.doctorid HAVING count(b.patientid)>1;
```

where have i gone wrong with the syntax?
Thanks...

Comment: do not mix the syntax, try `FROM billing b INNER JOIN doctor d` or `LEFT JOIN` to show doctors with no billing.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676763/sql-query-clarification-required). This one is much more clear :-)

Answer (score 1):

`FROM billing b,doctor d ON b.doctorid=d.doctorid` should be
`FROM billing b inner join doctor d ON b.doctorid=d.doctorid`

Comment: can't joins be performed without the keyword join?

Comment: It can be done, but it isn't strictly a join. It is a cartesian product (depending on the DBMS' optimizer might be translated to joins at runtime). In this case remember to specify the join condition `b.doctorid = d.doctorid` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You can do full join then add a where clause, that would look like the second example of Xavi

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `INNER JOIN` keyword, and you also need to `GROUP BY` all the non-aggregate columns you're using in the `SELECT` clause (`GROUP BY d.dname, b.doctorid` in this case).

Also, it might be a typo, but you haven't got a space between `Sum(b.fees)` and `as`:

```
SELECT d.dname, b.doctorid, Sum(b.fees) as "TotalFees" 
FROM billing b INNER JOIN doctor d ON b.doctorid=d.doctorid
GROUP BY d.dname, b.doctorid HAVING count(b.patientid)>1;
```

Remember using comma separated table names in a `FROM` clause will perform a cartesian product, which will be a performance killer depending on your RDBM's optimizer. In case you'd like to use it, remember to put its join conditions in the `WHERE` clause (the `ON` clause is used along with the `JOIN` syntax):

```
SELECT d.dname, b.doctorid, Sum(b.fees) as "TotalFees" 
FROM billing b, doctor d 
WHERE b.doctorid = d.doctorid
GROUP BY d.dname, b.doctorid HAVING count(b.patientid)>1;
```

Comment: @Dixon Glad that helped :) I see you've already asked some questions, but haven't yet accepted an answer to any of them. Remember it is of great value for the whole community and future visitors of this or other questions to have a clearly accepted answer. Please, take a look at [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/169503). And remember to upvote helpful answers and accept the one that solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mentioned into your query about which join you want to use,you have to change your query like

```
SELECT d.dname, b.doctorid, Sum(b.fees) as "TotalFees" 
FROM billing b inner join doctor d ON b.doctorid=d.doctorid
GROUP BY d.dname, b.doctorid HAVING count(b.patientid)>1;
```

Check [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT d.dname,b.doctorid,Sum(b.fees)as "TotalFees" FROM billing b inner join doctor d ON b.doctorid=d.doctorid
GROUP BY d.dname,b.doctorid HAVING count(b.patientid)>1;
```