# SQL Joins Clarification

Tags: sql, oracle

I wish to display the `hospitalid,hosp name and hosp type` for the hospital which have/has the highest no of doctors associated with them.

I have two tables:

Doctor: `doctorid, hospitalid`

Hospital: `hospitalid, hname, htype`

```
SELECT d.hospitalid,h.hname,h.htype 
FROM doctor d 
INNER JOIN hospital h ON d.hospitalid = h.hospitalid 
GROUP BY d.hospitalid,h.hname,h.htype 
HAVING MAX(count(d.doctorid));
```

I tried the above code, but i get an error "group func is nested too deeply". How should i modify d code?

Comment: is this mysql? sqlite?

Comment: This table layout could lead to reduntant data if you hold doctor information in the doctor table also, if the doctors could work at muliple hospitals.

Comment: Please do not spam stackoverflow. You can update you [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677679/sql-query-clarification) and ask it there. Stackoverflow is for problems, not for full code requests. So adjust your previous question and people will answer.

Comment: @Tikkes ok. Sorry. :)

Comment: @mnagel Yes it is mysql.

Comment: Since the error is an Oracle error, I have removed the mysql tag.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common error when learning SQL, thinking that `having Max(col)` says "keep only the row with the max".  It simply means `having <some function on the column>` *without any condition*.  For instance, you could say `having count(d.doctorid) = 1` to get hospitals with only one doctor.

The way to do this is to order the columns and then take the first row.  However, the syntax for "take the first row" varies by database.  The following works in many SQL dialects:

```
SELECT d.hospitalid,h.hname,h.htype
FROM doctor d INNER JOIN
     hospital h
     ON d.hospitalid = h.hospitalid 
GROUP BY d.hospitalid,h.hname,h.htype
order by count(d.doctorid) desc
limit 1;
```

In SQL Server and Sybase, the syntax is:

```
SELECT top 1 d.hospitalid,h.hname,h.htype
FROM doctor d INNER JOIN
     hospital h
     ON d.hospitalid = h.hospitalid 
GROUP BY d.hospitalid,h.hname,h.htype
order by count(d.doctorid) desc;
```

In Oracle:

```
select t.*
from (SELECT d.hospitalid,h.hname,h.htype
      FROM doctor d INNER JOIN
           hospital h
           ON d.hospitalid = h.hospitalid 
     GROUP BY d.hospitalid,h.hname,h.htype
     order by count(d.doctorid) desc
    ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

EDIT (based on comment):

To get all rows with the maximum, then you can do something similar to your original query.  It is just more complicated.  You can calculate the maximum number using a subquery and do the comparison in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT d.hospitalid, h.hname, h.htype
FROM doctor d INNER JOIN
     hospital h
     ON d.hospitalid = h.hospitalid  join
GROUP BY d.hospitalid,h.hname,h.htype
having count(d.doctorid) = (select max(NumDoctors)
                            from (select hospitalid, count(*) as NumDoctors
                                  from hospitalId
                                  group by hospitalid
                                 )  hd
                           )
```

As a note, there are easier mechanisms in other databases.

Comment: What if there are more than one rows with the top values. How do i isolate those rows in such a case?

Comment: @Dixon, that is a business requirements question that we cannot answer. Your business needs to determine what else would be the deciding factor if there are multiple rows.

Comment: @HLGEM I apologize if i am sounding a bit naive but my ultimate aim is to retrieve the rows with the max values and the above code wouldnt fetch me that, if i have two or more rows with the same max values right??

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write it for SQL Server. THe specific details might vary depending teh database backend you are using.

```
SELECT TOP 1 a.hospitalid,a.hname,a.htype
FROM 
(SELECT d.hospitalid,h.hname,h.htype, count(d.doctorid) as doctorcount FROM doctor d INNER JOIN hospital h ON d.hospitalid = h.hospitalid 
 GROUP BY d.hospitalid,h.hname,h.htype) a
ORDER BY doctorcount DESC;
```

Comment: HLGEM What if i dont want to display the doctorcount column?

Comment: I am getting this Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: That is an ORacle error. That means the SQl Server code I posted will not work on oracle.  It is critical when asking database questions to specify the database you are querying as the code is different for every database implementation.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I am using Oracle. Thank u.